# Как именно работает откат репутации?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Я всегда считал, что откат репутации пересчитывается задним числом и вычитается за соответствующую дату. Однако, сейчас я заметил, что вычитается он на следующий день. Но при этом за предыдущий всё равно есть пересчёт: сообщения, вклад которых в репутацию уменьшен из-за превышения дневного лимита оказались не последними, а одними из первых по времени голосования.

Хотелось бы узнать подробнее, как всё это устроено.

[image: сообщения после лимита]